# Tcl Tk hide Objects when user press Radiobuttons

Tags: radio-button, tcl, tk-toolkit

I cant find anything about Events in Gui-Programming in TK. If a user click on the Radio Button "automatic", the other RadioButtons should be invisible.

here is the code:

```
set base .example1;
toplevel $base
wm geometry $base 1920x1080

set frame_RadioBtnAuto [labelframe $base.frame_RadioBtnAuto \
        -text Search \
        -font {Calibri -12 bold} ];
place $frame_RadioBtnAuto -x 250 -y 135;

set rbl [radiobutton $frame_RadioBtnAuto.rbl \
        -text "Automatic"\
        -variable "[namespace current]::optionVariable" -value one ];
#Standardwahl beim start
$frame_RadioBtnAuto.rbl select
pack $rbl -side left -anchor nw;

set rb2 [radiobutton $frame_RadioBtnAuto.rb2 \
        -text "UserDef"\
        -variable "[namespace current]::optionVariable" -value two ];
pack $rb2 -side top -anchor nw;

set frame_RadioBtnUserW1 [labelframe $base.frame_RadioBtnUserACC \
        -text Window\ 1\
        -font {Calibri -12 bold} ];
place $frame_RadioBtnUserACC -x 250 -y 170;

set rba1 [radiobutton $frame_RadioBtnUserW1.rba1 \
        -text "Test1"\
        -variable "[namespace current]::optionVariable1" -value three ];
pack $rba1 -side top -anchor nw;

set rba2 [radiobutton $frame_RadioBtnUserW1.rba2 \
        -text "Test2"\
        -variable "[namespace current]::optionVariable1" -value four ];
pack $rba2 -side top -anchor nw;
```

Comment: How would someone deselect “`automatic`”?

Comment: @DonalFellows if the user dont want a random Arrangement. He can choose a Manual Option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the UI respond to a radiobutton change is fairly easy. You can either add a script via the radiobutton's `-command` option *or* you can set a write `trace` on the variable so that changing the variable triggers the UI change. I think you will find the latter is more reliable in anything like a complex UI:

```
trace add variable [namespace current]::optionVariable write optionVariableWritten
proc optionVariableWritten args {
    variable optionVariable
    if {$optionVariable eq "one"} {
        # Conceal the UI here
    } else {
        # Reveal the UI here
    }
}
```

You'll need to think carefully about exactly how to hide and show the UI; sometimes it gives a better (i.e., less surprising) experience to just disable the complex UI instead of hiding it entirely.